# Python - Locking a shared resource (Multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to send a trigger to to start the second process. Its like only after a certain time is passed, then only second process can start. Similar to locking a shared resource. How would I do it?

Here's my sample code :-

```
def worker():
    for i in range(1,10):
        if i == 5:
            # send a trigger to start the next event. 
            # Its like 'locking' a shared resource.

def main():
    for i in range(1,100):
        d = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = ())
        d.daemon = True
        d.start()
```

**Edited** (Expected Output)

```
Process1 loop1
Process1 loop2
Process1 loop3
Process1 loop4
1 2014-08-27 11:45:51.687848 # after this random numbers should get print.
Process2 loop1
Process2 loop2
Process2 loop3
Process2 loop4
Process1 loop5
Process1 loop6
Process1 loop7
Process1 loop8
Process1 loop9
2 2014-08-27 11:45:51.690052
Process2 loop5
Process2 loop6
Process2 loop7
Process2 loop8
Process2 loop9
```

**Current OUTPUT**

```
Process1 loop1
Process1 loop2
Process1 loop3
Process1 loop4
1 2014-08-27 11:45:51.687848
Process1 loop5
Process1 loop6
Process1 loop7
Process1 loop8
Process1 loop9
Process2 loop1
Process2 loop2
Process2 loop3
Process2 loop4
2 2014-08-27 11:45:51.690052
Process2 loop5
Process2 loop6
Process2 loop7
Process2 loop8
Process2 loop9
```

Comment: -1 for editing and completely changing what the question is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer to control processes by `Queue`. It gives you more flexibility because the process can perform different action based on commands in the queue.

```
import datetime
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

def worker(work_queue):
    if work_queue.get() == "Start":
            for i in range(1,10):
                if i == 5:
                    # do something
                    print datetime.datetime.now() 

def main():
    worker_queues = {}
    for i in xrange(1, 6):
        q = Queue()
        worker_queues[i] = q # one queue per process here
        d = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (q,))
        d.daemon = True
        d.start()
    for wq in worker_queues.values():
        wq.put("Start")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT**: In response to your edited question, you can enforce execution order by adding a `done queue` to the above solution

```
import datetime
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

def worker(myid, work_queue, done_queue):
    if work_queue.get() == "Start":
        for i in range(1,10):
                if i == 5:
                    # do something
                    print myid, datetime.datetime.now() 
        done_queue.put(myid)

def main():
    worker_queues = {}
    for i in xrange(1, 6): 
        q = Queue()
        done_q = Queue()
        worker_queues[i] = (q, done_q)
        d = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (i, q, done_q))
        d.daemon = True
        d.start()


    for i in xrange(1, 6): 
        worker_queues[i][0].put("Start")
        if worker_queues[i][1].get():
            # move to next iteration
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can understand this solution as a kind of message passing mechanism between processes.

Comment: Isnt there a  memory constraint? I mean I'm making a queue for every process.

Comment: Also, I want to send a trigger back from the worker to the main program (when i=5) that now the second process can start executing. But in your case, its completely different. Kindly explain if I'm incrorrect.

Comment: If you are going to fire a 100 processes already, 100 queue objects is probably a less of a concern in term of memory.

Comment: You can always add extra queue for interprocess communication. My code should have illustrated the underlying concept

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It indeed is very useful. Thanks for it. But now I'm in a dilemma, you solution looks perfect (as per my requirements) but `lock and acquire` also solves the purpose. Which one is recommended?

Comment: Queue is more flexible and extensible.

Comment: When I try your code, though it prints all the processes in order, but when i=5, it still continues printing for the same process. I rather want something like when i=5 for P1, then P2 should start printing upto 5, then P3 should and in between numbers upto 6-10 are printed for P1 and P2. Please habe a look at the expected output.